# Web2py: Database queries from within layout.html

Tags: mongodb, web2py

I'm interested in displaying recently searched terms (stored in a database) on every page of my application. At first glance, it seems like layout.html would be the best place for this function. I'd need to run database queries, and they'd look something like this:

```
{{import pymongo}}
{{db = pymongo.MongoClient()}}
{{result = db.collection.distinct("search_term")}}
{{etc...}}
```

I'm not sure it's the wisest idea. In terms of security, should I be concerned about running database queries from a view? Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no security issue, as the view is executed on the server. However, a better practice would be to move that code to a model file, and then simply display the result in the layout (any objects defined in a model file will be available in the view's execution environment).

In a model file:

```
import pymongo
db = pymongo.MongoClient()
result = db.collection.distinct("search_term")
```

And then in layout.html:

```
{{for record in result:}}
[code to display record]
{{pass}}
```

Another option would be to move the code to a module and simply import and call a function in the layout (the idea is to limit the views to display-related code only, particularly since it is a little harder to read and debug Python code in the views).

Comment: ah, good call. i'm already doing something similar in db.py, but for some reason it didn't occur to me to put this there too. nevertheless, glad no additional security issues in this type of implementation.